# Ubuntu get PostGreSQL running

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I have installed PostGreSQL 8.3 on an Ubuntu machine and I want to configure a pssw for it, however when I run this command:

sudu su postgres -c psql template1

I get the following error:

"psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?"

Can anybody tell me how I can check if the db server is running locally (only accepting connections on localhost)?

How I can start the psql server?

I'm a Linux newbie, btw

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can know the status of your Postgres server via the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.3 status
```

To start it you can issue the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.3 start
```

and to stop you can issue the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.3 stop
```

Comment: so it was down, attempting to start it, it says it cannot load file server.cert?

Comment: This happens when postgres ssl is turned on and the certificates is not there. What you can do is open the file /etc/postgresql/8.3/main/postgresql.conf ,there is a line when says ssl = true change that to ssl = false and then start your serevr

Answer (score 22):

First, check whether the server is running or not. The command for checking this is:

```
service postgresql status
```

it will check the status of server if you found

> postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
>
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor pres
>
> Active: inactive (dead)

Then you have to restart the server by the given command and mostly this problem is coming in 9.6.1 version of PostgreSQL.

```
service postgresql restart
```

Then the PostgreSQL server will run correctly in Ubuntu terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can also start and stop `postgres` server without specifying version:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

`start` - to start server

`stop` - to stop server

`status` - to know status, whether server is running or not

Answer (score 1):

Most Recent

To check if it is running:

`sudo systemctl status postgresql@13-main`

To start it:

`sudo systemctl start postgresql@13-main`

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl status postgresql
```

was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It is actually

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql@13-main
```

where `13` is your installed postgres version. To actually check for your postgres version, you will have to open a postgres interface. For example like this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

and execute

```
select version()
```